# Combining two preg_replace into one

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to combine those 2 preg_replace into a single one.For example replace every `data-thumb-bg="` with `style="background-image: url('` and **after that** if there is `.jpg` replace it with `.jpg);`.

```
 $input = preg_replace('#data-thumb-bg="#s', 'style="background-image: url(', $input);
 $input = preg_replace('#.jpg#s', '.jpg);', $input); //this must be executed only if a match has been found for above
```

How can i do that ?

**Edit**

I think i have wrongly expressed myself

The `.jpg` should be replaced **only if** `data-thumb-bg=` has been replaced.Like first you replace the `data-thumb-bg` then  you replace the `.jpg` that follow the `data-thumb-bg`

Kind Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your end goal is to change an element's attribute `data-thumb-bg="photo.jpg"` to `style="background-image: url(photo.jpg);"`. This can be done using a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) (note that the [`s` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) is unnecessary since we don't use a `.`):

```
$input = preg_replace('/data-thumb-bg="([^"]+)"/', 'style="background-image: url(\1);"', $input);
```

[***RegEx Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/vB1fQ8/1)

---

If you want to only allow [`.jpg` extensions](http://regex101.com/r/vB1fQ8/2), you can use this expression:

```
data-thumb-bg="([^"]+?\.jpg)"
```

Or if you only want to allow [a handful of image extensions](http://regex101.com/r/vB1fQ8/3), you can use an expression like this:

```
data-thumb-bg="([^"]+?\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass array's to the pattern and replacement parameters in [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$pattern = array('#data-thumb-bg="#s', '#.jpg#s');
$replace = array('style="background-image: url(', '.jpg);');
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $input);
```

Comment: indeed it works too, but keep in mind that when you use an array of patterns, the target string is parsed once by pattern (as with `str_replace`)